# It is Possible to connect the site page with layout pages sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

it is possible to connect the site pages with layout page in sharepoint 2010. I did but i got the problem when i am save the data ie Publish the page it will give me error follwoing error:

> Error An unexpected error has
>   occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   9bc41e28-4fe1-4b4f-9e00-0e0494ef9e6e
>
> Date and Time: 7/1/2010 3:30:29 AM

Please any one have idea. Please solve my problem thanks Waiting for your response. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Log files in the **14\Logs** folder and search for the **Correlation ID: 9bc41e28-4fe1-4b4f-9e00-0e0494ef9e6e** . You should get more specific error information that will help to dig deep in to the issue.

Also try to enable **CustomError=Off** & **CallStack="True"** in the **Web.config** file.